# Calling macro from another workbook error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call a macro from another workbook, and I keep getting the following error.

Cannot run the macro

```
'IMECM_To...
```

The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I have made sure the macro name is spelled correctly, and have made sure that the macro is spelled correctly.
I have looked online and have not been able to figure out how to fix this.
Thanks

Here is the code

```
Sub move()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MacroFolder As String
Dim MacroWb As String

MacroFolder = "C:\Users\zhill\Desktop\macro learn\"
MacroWb = "IMECM_To_LDW_CSV_Format-20151023-for-2015Q3-for-udf-version-13.0.015.xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MacroFolder & MacroWb)

wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Cells(13, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("IntexFolderList").Cells(1, 1)
wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Cells(14, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("OutputFolderList").Cells(1, 1)
wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Cells(9, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("RunNbr").Cells(1, 1)

wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Application.Run (MacroWb & "!ALFAtoCorpCsvFormat")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the workbook name includes **spaces** or some other particular characters it is necessary to enclose the name with single quotes, like this :

```
Application.Run "'Book 1.xls'!MyMacroName"
```

**Source**: Ron deBruin : [**How do I use Application.Run in Excel?**](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm)

---

To ensure that macros are not disabled in Excel, you could go:
`File`>`Options`>`Trust Center`>`Trust Center Settings`>`Macro Settings`>`Enable All Macros`

Answer (score 0):

code looks fine, probably you need to do some debugging to rule out wrong filename 
press CTRL G , which will open your Immediate Window

type in the debug.print commands as below , if the line "Exists?" is follow by an empty space it means there's a problem with your file name or directory.

hit F8 to run the code line by line instead of F5

```
Sub move()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MacroFolder As String
Dim MacroWb As String

MacroFolder = "C:\Users\zhill\Desktop\macro learn\"
MacroWb = "IMECM_To_LDW_CSV_Format-20151023-for-2015Q3-for-udf-version-13.0.015.xlsm"

Debug.Print MacroFolder & MacroWb
Debug.Print "Exists?", Dir(MacroFolder & MacroWb)

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MacroFolder & MacroWb)

wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Cells(13, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("IntexFolderList").Cells(1, 1)
wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Cells(14, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("OutputFolderList").Cells(1, 1)
wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Cells(9, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("RunNbr").Cells(1, 1)

wb.Sheets("ALFA to Corp CSV").Application.Run (MacroWb & "!ALFAtoCorpCsvFormat")

End Sub
```

if you still cant seem to arrow into the problem 
run this code to see what are the files that excel has picked up in your directory.

```
Sub PrintDirectoryFiles()

Dim myfile As String
Dim MacroFolder As String

MacroFolder = "C:\Users\zhill\Desktop\macro learn\"
myfile = Dir(MacroFolder & "*.xlsm")  'or *.*

Do While myfile <> ""
    Debug.Print myfile
    myfile = Dir
Loop



End Sub
```